# setting an internal .txt file for GUI and Retrieving text from that .txt file

Tags: java

My project has 2 jframes named "main" and "NameEdit".

nameedit has 8 textfields that changes 8 jbuttons names on main frame.

I can change the names on the jbuttons and send the names to a text file, but I cant retrieve the saved names from that text file on program restart. I would like to jbutton names to be stored in a text file. so on program restart the jbutton names will always be until changed through the jframe nameedit textfields.

I would also like to make the text file internal to the java program instead of it being saved to the desktop. not sure how to set up a file directory.

```
 private void SaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
File file = new File ("textfld.txt");
     try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file)) {
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp1s.getText());
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp2s.getText());
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp3s.getText());
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp4s.getText());
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp5s.getText());
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp6s.getText());
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp7s.getText());
         out.println(NameEdit.Emp8s.getText());
         out.close();
     } catch(IOException ex){
         System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n",ex);           
     }

      try {
         Scanner In = new Scanner(file);
          while(In.hasNextLine()){
          String e1 = In.nextLine();
          System.in.println(e1);

            // In.nextLine();

       //  System.out.println("Emp1s"); 
     } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        // exception.printstackTrace();
     } 
}

Main.Emp1.setText(NameEdit.Emp1s.getText());
Main.Emp2.setText(NameEdit.Emp2s.getText());
Main.Emp3.setText(NameEdit.Emp3s.getText());
Main.Emp4.setText(NameEdit.Emp4s.getText());
Main.Emp5.setText(NameEdit.Emp5s.getText());
Main.Emp6.setText(NameEdit.Emp6s.getText());
Main.Emp7.setText(NameEdit.Emp7s.getText());
Main.Emp8.setText(NameEdit.Emp8s.getText());       
this.dispose();

}
```

Also I'm new to programing and self learning.

Comment: when your problem is at program start, why don't you show the initialization of the Frame(s)?

Comment: I haven't added any code in frame initialization block. Is that where I should put the scanner at? Or should I be using a different type of reader?

Comment: *"... initialization block. Is that where I should put the scanner at?"* ih you want the data to be read at startup, what other place could be usefull?

Comment: *"Or should I be using a different type of reader?"* I thing scanner is misused quite often. In your case the (Buffered)`FileReader`  would be much more suitable for reading the file.